# OpenMP conditional parallelization - syntax for if clause in parallel sections

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

A parallel section template is:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections{
    #pragma omp section{
        //parallelized
    }
    #pragma omp section{
        //parallelized
    }
}
```

What is the right way to conditionally parallelize this using the `if clause` ?

Is it sufficient to add `if (condition)` to the outermost `#pragma` or does is need to be specified in each inner `#pragma` as well?

```
#pragma omp parallel sections if(condition){
    #pragma omp section{ //is if(condition) needed here also?
        //parallelized or serialized depending on if(condition)
    }
    #pragma omp section{ //is if(condition) needed here also?
        //parallelized or serialized depending on if(condition)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OpenMP 4.5 docs](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) the syntax of theparallel sectionsconstruct is as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections [clause[[,] clause...]
{
# pragma omp section
  {
  }
# pragma omp section
  {
  }
}
```

So you should put if-clause only at the outer `#pragma`.
And (at least for my experience with OpenMP it was so) you should put `{` at the new line following pragma-statement but not at the end of it. Because any `#pragma` statement is a preprocessor macro and `{` is not parsed by it.